# Uploading file in MVC4 without refreshing form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4 and Jquery. 
The problem is that I have created a form in which user enters all the details and is supposed to upload an image for which I referred to [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/WKNQ120113-How-to-upload-a-file-in-MVC4.html) tutorial. But once the file is uploaded, the information which the user has entered is lost as the whole page refreshes itself. 
 I dont want the whole form to refresh/loss of information. How can I possibly do this?

Here's the code:

**Home Controller**(contains 2 action methods-**FileUpload** and **CreateLibrary**):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

**FileUpload** Action Method-

```
    public ActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
            else if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 3; //3 MB
                string[] AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf", ".docx", ".doc" };

                if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please file of type: " + string.Join(", ", AllowedFileExtensions));
                }

                else if (file.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Your file is too large, maximum allowed size is: " + MaxContentLength + " MB");
                }
                else
                {
                    //TO:DO
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**CreateLibrary** Action Method-

```
   public ActionResult CreateLibrary()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("CreateLibrary")]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult CreateLibRes(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection data)//string ResultXml)//
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Creating library");
        //  string path = Server.MapPath("~/Xsd");
        string strMyXml = Request.Form["ResultXml"].ToString();//data.Get("ResultXml");// "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Library xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/LibraryElements.xsd\"></Library>";// Request.Form["ResultXml"].ToString();//
        //MessageBox.Show("Here:\n" + strMyXml);
        string filename = Request.Form["LibName"].ToString();
        if (filename != "")
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(strMyXml);
            xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Xsd/" + filename + ".library.xml"));
            MessageBox.Show("Library Saved!");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Library name not specified!");
        return View();
    }
```

Form for uploading file (**CreateLibrary.cshtml**):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <ol>
            <li class="lifile">
                <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
                <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
    }
```

Validating the file on client side:**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
//get file size
function GetFileSize(fileid) {
    try {
        var fileSize = 0;
        //for IE
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            //before making an object of ActiveXObject,
            //please make sure ActiveX is enabled in your IE browser
            var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var filePath = $("#" + fileid)[0].value;
            var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
            var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
            fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb
        }
            //for FF, Safari, Opeara and Others
        else {
            fileSize = $("#" + fileid)[0].files[0].size //size in kb
            fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb
        }
        return fileSize;
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Error is :" + e);
    }
}

//get file path from client system
function getNameFromPath(strFilepath) {
    var objRE = new RegExp(/([^\/\\]+)$/);
    var strName = objRE.exec(strFilepath);

    if (strName == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return strName[0];
    }
}

$("#btnSubmit").live("click", function () {
    if ($('#fileToUpload').val() == "") {
        $("#spanfile").html("Please upload file");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return checkfile();
    }
});

function checkfile() {
    var file = getNameFromPath($("#fileToUpload").val());
    if (file != null) {
        var extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
        // alert(extension);
        switch (extension) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'png':
            case 'gif':
            case 'pdf':
                flag = true;
                break;
            default:
                flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false) {
        $("#spanfile").text("You can upload only jpg,png,gif,pdf extension file");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var size = GetFileSize('fileToUpload');
        if (size > 3) {
            $("#spanfile").text("You can upload file up to 3 MB");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#spanfile").text("");
        }
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#fileToUpload").change(function () {
        checkfile();
    });
});
</script>
```

Please guide me! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Stephen I have used the code exactly as in the tutorial. Additionally I have a CreateLibrary.cshtml View file which contains the form fields and a CreateLibrary action method in Home Controller, in addition to FileUpload action method as explained in the tutorial!

Comment: And the link may be dead tomorrow making this question useless!

Comment: Got the point, will add all the code, but please give an answer if you got my question and have a solution!

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to move the above comments to chat..and clicked on "automatically move this discussion to chat". Is there any other thing lacking in question sir?

Comment: Sorry to be harsh but that code is nonsense. Look at your first POST method. The model is `HttpPostedFileBase ` so how could `ModelState` be invalid. Then you add errors using `ModelState.AddModelError` but never return a model (just `return View()`). You even use `ModelState.Clear();` when there was never anything in `ModelState` in the first place Its all pointless, as is most of the code.

Comment: If you want to post a file and stay on the same page, use ajax and `FormData`. Refer [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).

Comment: The whole FileUpload() Action Method is from the tutorial. As I told before, I don't have much idea about MVC and its coding practices, so I just used it without knowing these things.

Comment: Find another tutorial (its rubbish) :) But why do you not want to just post the form and the file back at the same time?

Comment: Oh yes! I had done it seperately because I needed the location of the image file on the machine, I didn't realize that all the images from local machine would be going to same folder..thanks! ^^
Having said that I do want to use the code for uploading a file in some other application withing the same project, like uploading your resume on linked in, for example. When we click on upload, the rest of the field values stay.

Comment: @user3024292 `MessageBox.Show` is Windows Forms mechanism to show dialog boxes. @Stephen-Muecke I wonder where do those messages show up?

Comment: @CrnaStena They show up in a seperate window(dialog boxes) on your browser(not sure how this is related to my question though)